# Upsert Row If Columns Don't Match

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10, upsert

I have a table with unique identifier `sid`, `somecolumn` and boolean `changed` that is needed by other program to detect change in row, I'm using `insert into ... on conflict (sid) DO UPDATE ...` to insert data that's not already in there, but I also want to update `somecolumn` and set `changed` to true, only if `somecolumn` doesn't match excluded one.

to make it bit clearer

- if `sid` doesn't exist, insert data
- if `sid` exists and `somecolumn` matches excluded `somecolumn, do nothing
- if `sid` exists and `somecolumn` doesn't match, update `somecolumn` with new value
  and set `changed` to true

is there clean way to do this? I'd prefer to do this without making multiple queries,  I'm inserting hundreds of values in each query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a WHERE clause to the UPDATE part of an INSERT ... ON CONFLICT

```
insert into the_table (sid, somecolumn)
values (...)
on conflict (sid) do update 
  set somecolumn = excluded.somecolumn, 
      changed = true
where the_table.somecolumn <> excluded.somecolumn;
```

If you need to deal with NULL values in `somecolumn` use

```
where the_table.somecolumn is distinct from excluded.somecolumn
```